# Change button on-click event creating exponetially increasing events

Tags: c#, button, onclick

Have a simple application with a start/stop button that I want to do different things depending on it's current state.  If button is in Start state, execute code then change to stop state and change OnClick event to StopButton_Click and vice versa.

Can't seem to change the on-click property of the button, so using code below which works, but keeps adding instances of the event.  First click executes once, second click executes twice, third executes four times, ad infinitum.

```
StartButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(StartButton_Click);
```

alternates with

```
StartButton.Click += new System.EventHandler(StopButton_Click);
```

Is there a way to REPLACE the OnClick handler instead of adding to it?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the event handler before adding a new one:

StartButton.Click -= StartButton_Click;

Answer (score 1):

One option is to remove the previous event handler before adding another, but a simpler option is to just use a single event handler.  The event handler can look at some internal state field to determine what to do; this will likely be easier than constantly adding/removing event handlers.

It may look something like this:

```
private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if(buttonState == MyStateEnum.Start)
        PerformStartAction();
    else if(buttonState == MyStateEnum.Stop)
        PerformStopAction();
}
```

Then instead of adding/removing event handlers you just need to assign a different value to `buttonState`.

Answer (score 0):

`+=` works with events as it does anything else. It adds to what is already there.

Try removing the existing event handler with -= and then adding the new one.